# Git merge reminder

Tags: git, merge, automation

I have a develop branch, where new features for future releases are developed, and release branch, where all the bug fixing takes place. Develop branch can't be merged into release, but release should be often merge into develop. However, we often forget to do that merge, leading to pointlessly hard merges later.

Is there a way to automatically remind developers to merge a branch into another branch? In this case, for example, I want to show the reminder if the release branch has at least 5 commits not merged into develop. Is there a ready solution for that?

Comment: To clarify: this is not "do this thing for me" question, it's more of a "have this thing already been done" question.

Comment: searhc `git post commit hook`

Comment: @farmer1992 I figured that solution to this problem would use git hooks, but I couldn't find anything more specific about this particular situation

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to count commits in branch `X` that are not reachable from branch `Y`:

```
git rev-list X --not Y | wc -l
```

(the former generates a list of all commit revisions reachable from `X` but not `Y`, and `wc` counts lines because we restricted it with `-l`).

There's a shorter syntax for "X but not Y", spelled with the `..` syntax: it looks a little odd but you can just write `Y..X`.  In this case `Y` is `develop` and `X` is `release`, so `git rev-list develop..release` generates the list.

So (untested):

```
#! /bin/sh
n=$(git rev-list develop..release | wc -l)
if [ $n -ge 5 ]; then
    echo "NOTE: release has $n commits that are not yet merged into develop"
fi
```

As a post-commit hook (mentioned in comments), this would have to be run by each interested developer to remind them.